# Misaligned Rows in DataTable with Frozen Columns in Primefaces 5.0 JSF 2.2

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

Good morning to all of you . My problem is I have a DataTable With 48 columns , 4 of Which are frozen and own a scroll widht and height , and when I make a scroll to the last row , the frozen columns With The other columns are misaligned . I 'm using Primefaces 5.0, JSF 2.2, Chrome as browser, Eclipse IDE and Windows 8 as OS.

Annex the code of my Datatable and the a Column, Which is Practically the same for all other columns , the only variable is  the width:

```
<p:dataTable id="listado" var="tran" value="#{BEAN}" scrollable="true"
    scrollHeight="274" scrollWidth="48%" frozenColumns="4"
    selectionMode="single" selection="#{BEAN}"
    rowKey="#{BEAN}" dblClickSelect="true">
```

And the columns...

```
<p:column headerText="Header" style="width:90px">
        <h:outputText value="#{BEAN}" />
</p:column>
```

By the way , The Implementation That I have, I can not use Paginator , and I have been tried giving a Height for each one of the columns , I am using the theme of bootstrap and all that i have been  tested has worsened , the misalignment is now close to 3 or 4 pixels, but I want to remove it.

P.S. Sorry if my english is bad , I'm Hispanic speaker , and thank you very much in advance for your help . greetings :)

Comment: Did you try a newer version of PF?

Answer (score 0):

As long as liveScroll isn't enabled on the datatable, adding a bottom-border with the same height as the table rows to "listado_frozenTbody" should do the trick.

```
#listado_frozenTbody {
    border-bottom: 25px solid #E1E1E1;
}
```

Tested in Firefox 36.0 and Chrome 41.0.